# SQL join count(*) of one table to another table as aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table, users and comments.

In the users table, there're columns id and username. 
In the comments table I have user_id and his message.

And I wanted to create a table that select the username and his comment count when I search a particular username.

How do I write this?

my testing attempt:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment_count
 FROM song_comments
 RIGHT JOIN users
 WHERE user_id = 7 AND comments.user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT U.Username, COUNT(SC.message) AS comment_count
 FROM song_comments SC JOIN 
      users U ON U.id=SC.user_id
 WHERE U.user_id = 7
 GROUP BY U.Username
```

Comment: Thanks, I change the WHERE clause to U.id=7 and it works

Answer (score 0):

This gives you users and count

```
select u.username, count(c.user_id) as comment_count
from users u
join comments c on u.id = c.user_id
group by u.username
```

You can add a where to get one user's count

```
select u.username, count(c.user_id) as comment_count
from users u
join comments c on u.id = c.user_id
where u.username = 'Hogan'
group by u.username
```